# Getting URL with PHP $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I try to print the current URL but there's small problem with encoding. In my URL there can be letters like ä and ä but these shows up like this %C3%B6 when I print the URL.

Any idea where the problem is? PHP seettings, code or..? :)

Comment: can you post some code to check?

Comment: [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) perhaps?

Comment: Just pass it through `urldecode()` to resolve to the characters the escape sequences represent. Make sure the charset of the document you output is correct so they are rendered correctly by the client.

Comment: as a matter of fact, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] does contain already decoded value. there is a mistake somewhere else

Answer (score 9):

Try to `urldecode()` your string.

Answer (score 4):

If there are UTF8 characters in the request URI that are breaking, try this:

```
rawurldecode($_SERVER['UNENCODED_URL']);
```